# Galois extension characterization

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field, alternative-proof

Why to mention or why to give a basis for $E$ over $F?$ Why to make a relation between the basis and the minimal polynomial?

I think the proof is missing the 'therefore $E/F$ is Galois' at the end of the proof, anyway Why can we conclude that it's a Galois extension?

> A finite extension $E/F$ is Galois if and only if $E/F$ is normal and separable.

Proof (just this side $\gets$):

Suppose $E/F$ is normal and separable.

If $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ is a basis for $E$ over $F,$ let $f_i(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $w_i.$

Then $E/F$ is a splitting field for the product of $f_i$ and each $f_i$ is separable because $E/F$ is separable.

Comment: What's your defintion of a Galois extension? Personally, mine is that it is separable and normal..

Comment: @Ravi $K:F$ is a Galois extension if $G(K:F)^+=f(F),$ where $f$ is the monomorphism

Comment: There are many equivalent definitions Galois extensions. One of the most useful is there is a finite set $G$ (or group) of automorphisms of finite order $ \in Aut(E/F)$ such that $F = E^G$ the field fixed by each $\sigma \in G$. This means we can build the minimal polynomial of any $\alpha \in E$ once we know $G$.

Comment: Here I assume "decompose field" means "splitting field" and just wasn't translated well. This proof feels like half of it is missing (and I'm not talking about the $\to$ direction). I am guessing that there is some previous theorem which states that a separable splitting field is Galois. Otherwise it doesn't make sense for the proof to stop there.

Comment: @T.Gunn yes, 'decompose field' is the "splitting field", and again yes there was a theorem (that I haven't seen it before) that states: A finite $E/F$ is Galois iff it is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $p(x)$ over $F$. So second question is answered

Comment: and my first question?, I've seen some proofs (similar to this topics) that include that thing about basis and work with them but I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to use a previous theorem that if $E/F$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial then $E/F$ is Galois. We know that $E/F$ is normal and separable.

- Normal means that if $\alpha \in E$ then all the conjugates of $\alpha$ are in $E$. If $f_{\alpha}(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ then the roots of $f$ are the conjugates of $\alpha$ so $f_{\alpha}(x)$ has all of its roots in $E$ (it splits).
- Separable means that every minimal polynomial is a separable polynomial.

Thus for every element $\alpha \in E$ we get a separable polynomial $f_{\alpha}$ that splits. If there are infinitely many elements of $E$ then this doesn't help us so much. We use the finiteness condition to conclude that $E$ can be generated by a finite set $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$. That is, $E = F[\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]$.

Now we take the corresponding minimal polynomials $f_1 = f_{\alpha_1}, \dots, f_n = f_{\alpha_n}$. We know that $E$ is the splitting field of $f_1,\dots,f_n$ because the splitting field contains $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and they generate $E$.

Finally the last trick is to note that if $E$ is the splitting field of $f_1,\dots,f_n$ then $E$ is the splitting field of the product $f := f_1 \cdots f_n$. The polynomial $f$ is separable because each irreducible factor $f_1,\dots,f_n$ is separable.

Therefore $E/F$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial and we can apply the previous result.

Comment: didn't you miss ...conjugates of $\alpha \in E...$?, you just wrote ...conjugates of $E$...

Comment: @AnneliseToft Yes, thanks

Comment: For this side ($\gets $) we don't have the finiteness condition, do we?. Finiteness and Galois is for this direction ($\to$)

Comment: @AnneliseToft You're not parsing the statement correctly. Imagine it has parentheses like so: "A finite extension E/F (is Galois if and only if E/F is normal and separable)." That is, the finite extension E/F is Galois if and only if the finite extension E/F is normal and separable.

Comment: oh ok, so 'a finite extension $ E/F$' It's like a general hypothesis, for both sides.

Comment: @AnneliseToft exactly

Comment: and how would I know that the theorem is interpreted like that? I think there must be at least a '$,$' to know about it. This problem might appear in another theorem that I might read in the future

Comment: or maybe the first hypothesis of every theorem is a general hypothesis?

Comment: @AnneliseToft I guess there is a combination of English not being your first language and being new to mathematical statements working against you here. Here's how I understand it. The statement is of the form "An X is A if and only if it is B$. Here the if and only if connects the two parts "is A" and "is B" which begin with "is". Each part alone doesn't make sense: "is A" isn't a statement because is needs a subject. Thus the statement is "X is A" and similarly "X is B". So we have "X is A iff X is B". In the given statement "X" is "a finite extension E/F".

Comment: Ooh I like the explanation :)

Comment: Why the finiteness condition implies that the set $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ generates E? is it a result of a theorem?. I know that $F[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]=<\sigma(F)\bigcup (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)>$, but why is this equal to $E?$

Comment: @AnneliseToft Finite means finite dimensional. That is there is some basis $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ for the $F$-vector space $E$ such that every element of $E$ can be written as a sum $x_1\alpha_1 + \dots + x_n\alpha_n$ with $x_1,\dots,x_n \in F$. The notation $F[\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]$ means we take every polynomial in $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ with coefficients in $F$. Every element of $E$ can be written as $x_1\alpha_1 + \dots + x_n\alpha_n$ which is a linear polynomial. Thus $E = F[\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]$.

Comment: ok so your argument has no relation with this $F[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]=<\sigma(F)\bigcup (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)>,$ right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62669/discussion-between-t-gunn-and-annelise-toft).